# Randomly occurring error during publishing: "An error occurred while communicating with Topology Manager"

Tags: publishing, web8

When I try to bulk publish more than just a few pages, most of the transactions fail. The only error message I get is *"An error occurred while communicating with Topology Manager"*.

Strangely enough, this is not recorded in the event logs. I can't find anything in the logs on our CM server of the incident either.

I realize this is a thin problem description, but does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: Publishing queue]
[image: Error message]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am also facing the same